# How to put data from html form into django form?

Tags: python, html, django

Html form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'blog:add_comment' article.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea type="text" id="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Django form:

```
class NewComment(forms.Form):
    text = forms.TextInput()
```

add_comment view:

```
def add_comment(request, article_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewComment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']

    return redirect('blog:detail', article_id)
```

I'm trying to validate comment with django form, but it's cleary dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned a `name` to your textarea.  That's what is used to assign form fields, not the `id`:

```
    <textarea type="text" name="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
```